"MismatchSenderId" for Android platform when sending push notifications
We are currently facing an issue with sending push notifications to Android devices. In the push extract, we encounter a "SenderId mismatch" error with a status of "Fail". This issue affects 90% of our Android devices, while the remaining 10% receive notifications successfully.
We have verified that the SenderId in our SDK configuration matches the one in the Firebase Console. Additionally, we have updated the Service Account JSON file in the Administration panel, but the issue persists. FCM token is no longer used after Salesforce update.
When conducting tests via the Administration panel (Test Configuration), we receive a Service Status of "Forbidden" and a Failure Type of "MismatchSenderId" within the Push Job section. All sections "turn green" except Send Status which displays a message "Push Not Sent".
Sadly we are only the support to the actual mobile dev team that implemented the SDK. While looking at the problem, one problem comes to mind and that is the "Multiple Push Provider". Dev team is quite certain that they are not using any other push providers. For some reason this problem did not occur for our testing application or maybe that was just luck.
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Open a support case, but I can tell you this is easily fixed by reconciling all the pieces of data: The projectId (aka senderId) you've configured in your SDK is NOT from the same project from which you have provided your JSON authorization file to the server. That is the ONLY thing that returns the error you're receiving.

@BillMote Thank you, the dev team managed to find the problem and it was the senderId.

The projectId (aka senderId) you've configured in your SDK is NOT from the same project from which you have provided your JSON authorization file to the server. That is the ONLY thing that returns the error you're receiving.
